# Why is this formula wrong ? lie derivative tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-derivative

I have derived some formula for the lie derivative of a covariant tensor which seems wrong....

Let $X$ is vector field inducing a flow $\phi_t$ and $T$ a rank $2$ covariant tensor, I claim that

$$(\mathcal{L}_XT)(Y,Z)=T(\mathcal{L}_XY,Z)+T(Y,\mathcal{L}_XZ) $$

By definition we have that
$$(\mathcal{L}_XT)(Y,Z)=\frac{d}{dt}(\phi_{-t})_*T_{\phi_t(p)}(Y,Z) $$
Now by bi-linearity of $T$ we have:

\begin{align*}
(\phi_{-t})_*T_{\phi_t(p)}(Y,Z) &= T((\phi_{-t})*Y_{\phi_t(p)},(\phi_{-t})*Z_{\phi_t(p)}) \\
&=T((\phi_{-t})*Y_{\phi_t(p)}-Y,(\phi_{-t})*Z_{\phi_t(p)})+T(Y,(\phi_{-t})*Z_{\phi_t(p)})
\end{align*}
Hence
$$\frac{(\phi_{-t})_*T_{\phi_t(p)}(Y,Z)-T_p(Y,Z) }{t}=  T(\frac{(\phi_{-t})*Y_{\phi_t(p)}-Y}{t},(\phi_{-t})_*Z_{\phi_t(p)}) +T(Y_p,\frac{(\phi_{-t})*Z_{\phi_t(p)}-Z_p}{t}) $$

We conclude by taking the limit as $t$ goes to $0$ using the continuity of $T$.

Comment: I think there are three variables $Y,Z$ and the coefficients in $T$, which will change as the transformation of $X$. For example, $T(Y,Z)|_p=a(p)Y(p)\bigotimes Z(p)$. The result can be obtained from the Leibniz rule.

Comment: I see, I forgot to put the proper subscript $T_p$ or $T_{\phi_t(p)}$ at some places making the third coefficient $a(p)$ a constant.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: For the record, the correct formula is $$(\mathcal{L}_XT)(Y,Z) = X(T(Y,Z)) - T(\mathcal{L}_XY,Z) - T(Y,\mathcal{L}_XZ).$$

Comment: I derived the wrong formula trying to prove this one. It seems the correct way is to use coordinates or to use the fact that Lie derivative commutes with contraction